# Java Script: OnMouseOver

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Нужно решить такой вопрос:

```
document.getElementById('sec_info').innerHTML = '1';
```

Этот код меняет содержимое блока, окей, дальше, мне нужно вычислить, при каком условии это делать. А условие следующее: при наведении на блок (div) А, выполняем этот код (вышенаписанный). Т.е. получится, говоря по нубски, следующее:

```
if (onMouseOver div A) document.getElementById('sec_info').innerHTML = '1';
```

Помогите решить задачу :) Ах, и да, обязательное условие - реализация именно на чистом JS, не на JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

<div id="sec_info">2</div>

document.getElementById('sec_info').onmouseenter = function() {
    this.innerHTML = '1'
}

http://jsfiddle.net/B36nk/

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Мда, рано порадовался... Код нерабочий. Мне нужно что бы при наведении на блок А, менялось содержимое (текст) блока Б.

Answer (score 1):

Всё там рабочее:

```
document.getElementById('hover_block').onmouseenter = function() {
    document.getElementById('sec_info').innerHTML = '1'
}
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/B36nk/1/